# add userid field to zend db logger

Tags: php, mysql, logging, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Id like to add a field that contains the user id from the logged in user into the `zend db logger`.

Here is my current code:

```
$mapping = array(
        'timestamp' => 'created',
        'priorityName'  => 'type',
        'message'   => 'message'                
);      
$dbAdapter = Pluto::database()->getMasterAdapter();
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Db($dbAdapter,'logs',$mapping);
$this->logger->addWriter($writer);
```

My userid column will be `userid`. If the user is not logged in then it should insert 0.

Not quite sure what to do here.

**UPDATE**

Here's my current processor:

```
namespace Pluto\Log;

use Zend\Log\Processor\ProcessorInterface;

class UserAwareProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $event event data
     * @return array event data
     */
    public function process(array $event)
    {
        if (! isset($event['extra'])) {
            $event['extra'] = [];
        }

        $event['extra']['userid'] = 5;

        return $event;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [log processor](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/processors/) to easily append/prepend any data to your logs just before writing. Since processors are called from the logger before the log event is passed to the writer, I would create `MyApp\Log\UserAwareProcessor` with a following signature and body:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Log;

use Zend\Log\Processor\ProcessorInterface

class UserAwareProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $event event data
     * @return array event data
     */
    public function process(array $event)
    {
        if (! isset($event['extra'])) {
            $event['extra'] = [];
        }

        $event['extra']['userId'] = $this->getUserId();

        return $event;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    private function getUserId()
    {
        // Read the id from session or any other source and return it 
    }
}
```

At the end, after setting a writer to your logger, you'll need also set the processor something like:

```
$this->logger->addWriter($writer);
$processor = new MyApp\Log\UserAwareProcessor();
$this->logger->addProcessor($processor);
```

You may also want to checkout [log formatters](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/formatters/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be updating in the database column userid. Check my updated code